# hibernate not using where clause with inner join

Tags: java, hibernate

Here's an excerpt from my code (I'm using XDoclet):

```
/**
 * @hibernate.class table="WIP_DISCRETE_JOBS"
 */
public class WipDiscreteJob extends AuditedObject
{
  private WipDiscreteJobStatus status;

  /**
   * @hibernate.many-to-one column="STATUS_TYPE"
   */
  public WipDiscreteJobStatus getStatus()
  {
    return status;
  }
}

/**
 * @hibernate.class
 *   table="apps.mfg_lookups"
 *   where="lookup_type = 'WIP_JOB_STATUS'"
 */
public class WipDiscreteJobStatus extends ManufacturingLookup
{
  /**
   * @hibernate.id column="LOOKUP_CODE"
   *   generator-class="assigned"
   */
  public Long getId()
  {
    return this.id;
  }

}
```

And here's some database definitions:

```
APPS.MFG_LOOKUP (view)
Column Name  Pk  Data Type            Null?
LOOKUP_TYPE      VARCHAR2 (30 Byte)   N
LOOKUP_CODE      NUMBER               Y

WIP_DISCRETE_JOBS
Column Name  Pk  Data Type            Null?
STATUS_TYPE  N   NUMBER               Yes
```

When I query on WipDiscreteJob and try to get a count of the results (using Criterias), the SQL, in part, looks like

```
select count(*) as y0_ 
from WIP_DISCRETE_JOBS this_ 
inner join apps.mfg_lookups       wipdiscret2_ on this_.STATUS_TYPE=wipdiscret2_.LOOKUP_CODE 
inner join WIP_ENTITIES           wipentity1_  on this_.WIP_ENTITY_ID=wipentity1_.WIP_ENTITY_ID 
inner join WIP_SCHEDULE_GROUPS    wipschedul4_ on this_.SCHEDULE_GROUP_ID=wipschedul4_.SCHEDULE_GROUP_ID 
inner join INV.MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B item3_       on this_.PRIMARY_ITEM_ID=item3_.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID and this_.ORGANIZATION_ID=item3_.ORGANIZATION_ID 
where wipentity1_.WIP_ENTITY_NAME is not null
  and wipdiscret2_.LOOKUP_CODE=3 
  and item3_.PLANNER_CODE='A5'
  and wipschedul4_.SCHEDULE_GROUP_NAME='Area 2'
```

and I get an "invalid number" error when I run it. But when I add the "where" clause from the class...

```
select count(*) as y0_ 
from WIP_DISCRETE_JOBS this_ 
inner join apps.mfg_lookups       wipdiscret2_ on this_.STATUS_TYPE=wipdiscret2_.LOOKUP_CODE  AND lookup_type = 'WIP_JOB_STATUS'
inner join WIP_ENTITIES           wipentity1_  on this_.WIP_ENTITY_ID=wipentity1_.WIP_ENTITY_ID 
inner join WIP_SCHEDULE_GROUPS    wipschedul4_ on this_.SCHEDULE_GROUP_ID=wipschedul4_.SCHEDULE_GROUP_ID 
inner join INV.MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B item3_       on this_.PRIMARY_ITEM_ID=item3_.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID and this_.ORGANIZATION_ID=item3_.ORGANIZATION_ID 
where wipentity1_.WIP_ENTITY_NAME is not null
  and wipdiscret2_.LOOKUP_CODE=3 
  and item3_.PLANNER_CODE='A5'
  and wipschedul4_.SCHEDULE_GROUP_NAME='Area 2'
```

and run it manually, it runs fine. Is this just a bug in Hibernate or am I missing something? How do I get Hibernate to add that "where" clause?

Comment: I don't use any custom SQL. Hibernate generates the first query you see there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `status.lookup_type = 'WIP_JOB_STATUS'` to your criteria list.

You have not provided your query so it is not possible to fix that part.